# How should we be alerted of failures in the SQL replication distribution agent job?

Tags: sql-server, replication

When setting up SQL replication, the default retry count for the replication agent job step is 2147483647, retrying every minute. This means that if replication fails, the failure notification for the SQL Agent job won't be sent for 4085 years.

The issue is discussed in this MSDN blog, along with the suggestion that the retry count be changed from 2147483647 to 60 - so we would only wait one hour before being alerted to the failure:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/08/25/sql-replication-agent-will-retry-for-4085-years.aspx

However it seems to me that the Microsoft SQL team must have selected the default of 2147483647 for a reason, and changing it to a much lower value must therefore have some negative impact.

So the question is - what is the best way to be alerted when a subscription breaks?  (In our scenario, we are only the subscriber - and another company is the publisher)

Comment: How long can you afford to be without the data?  How is the data being replicated - push, pull, through a distributor?  How long would it take to reinitialize if it is broken after an hour?

Comment: You can use replication alert (in alert - sql agent) to get you alerted. Your situation being as subscriber - with no access to Publication makes it difficult to configure alerts.